# Удалить заданные ключи в списке словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, словари

Есть список словарей вида:

```
[{"1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3"}, {"1": "4", "2": "5", "3": "6"}...]
```

Ключи в словарях одинаковые.
Как мне удалить ключ "2" и его значение из всех словарей?
Желательно **без использования сторонних модулей**...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Включениями конечно

```
data = [{"1":"1", "2":"2", "3":"3"}, {"1":"4", "2":"5", "3":"6"}, ...]

data = [{k: v for k, v in i.items() if k != '2'} for i in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [{"1":"1", "2":"2", "3":"3"}, {"1":"4", "2":"5", "3":"6"}, {}, ]
for d in data: d.pop('2', '')
```